# writing values in a file using multithreading in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I may ask a repeated question here.
but still i am not able to solve my problem.

I am try to  find a answer for below question.

Write a program to create 2 threads. Thread 1 will write numbers 1 to 10 with one second delay after every entry into an output file. Thread 2 will write numbers 1 to 10 with two second delay after every entry into the same output file.

wt i did

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

class Thread1 extends Thread
{
       public void run()
       {

              ThreadSample threadSample = new ThreadSample();
              try {
                     threadSample.printer(500);
              } catch (IOException e) {
                     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                     e.printStackTrace();
              }

       }
}
class Thread2 extends Thread
{
       public void run()
       {
              ThreadSample threadSample = new ThreadSample();
              try {
                     threadSample.printer(1000);
              } catch (IOException e) {
                     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                     e.printStackTrace();
              }

              /*{
                     try {
                           for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
                                  System.out.println(this.getName()+" "+i);

                                  Thread.sleep(1000);
                           } 
                     }
                     catch (InterruptedException e) {
                           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                           e.printStackTrace();
                     }
              }*/
       }
}

    public class ThreadSample extends Thread{

           public  void printer(int j) throws IOException{

                  FileWriter f = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\sample.txt");
                  //f.getAbsoluteFile();

                  BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter(f);

                  synchronized(this){
                         try {
                               FileWriter fw=new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\BK00354083\\Desktop\\sample.txt");



                               for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
                                      System.out.println(this.getName()+" "+i);
                                      br.write("values"+ i);
                                      br.newLine();
                                      Thread.sleep(j);
                               } 
                         }
                         catch (InterruptedException e) {
                               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                               e.printStackTrace();
                         }finally {
                               br.close();
                         }
                  }
           }

           public static void main(String args[]){
                  Thread1 t1=new Thread1();
                  Thread2 t2=new Thread2();

                  t1.start();
                  t2.start();
           }
    }
```

but it is writing one thread value into file.
so i changed my code like below

```
 import java.io.BufferedWriter;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileWriter;
    import java.io.IOException;

    class Thread1 extends Thread
    {
        public void run()
        {
            FileWriter f;
            try {
                f = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\sample.txt");

                BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter(f);           
                synchronized(this){
                    try {                        
                        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
                            System.out.println(this.getName()+" "+i);
                            br.write("values"+ i);
                            br.newLine();
                            Thread.sleep(500);
                        } 
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }finally {
                        br.close();
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }
    }
    class Thread2 extends Thread
    {
        public void run()
        {
            FileWriter f;
            try {
                f = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\sample.txt");

                BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter(f);           
                synchronized(this){
                    try {                        
                        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
                            System.out.println(this.getName()+" "+i);
                            br.append("values"+ i);
                            br.newLine();
                            Thread.sleep(500);
                        } 
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }finally {
                        br.close();
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }
    }

    public class ThreadSample extends Thread{
            public static void main(String args[]){
            Thread1 t1=new Thread1();
            Thread2 t2=new Thread2();
            t1.start();
            t2.start();
        }
    }
```

even it is also writing the same thread2 values only
Any help..!!!

Comment: I did not get complete problem. Are you getting output from one thread Or two threads in the same file?

Comment: Is it writing thread 2 values only, or thread 2 values first and then thread 1 values?  Are any exceptions being thrown from thread 1?

Comment: @ Ravindra babu
Two threads should write into same file

Comment: @WarrenDew
 Thread 1 will write numbers 1 to 10 with one second delay after every entry into an output file. Thread 2 will write numbers 1 to 10 with two second delay after every entry into the same output file.

Comment: That's what they should do, right?  My question was about what they are doing  now.

Comment: My code is writing the second thread value only.

Answer (score 0):

You second thread is not appending content to the file, which was written by first thread. Instead it is overwriting content written by first thread.

So you are getting output only from second thread.

Change your code

from

```
 FileWriter f = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\sample.txt");
```

to

```
 FileWriter f = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\sample.txt",true);
```

Refer to java documentation [page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter-java.io.File-boolean-) on `FileWriter`

```
public FileWriter(File file,
                  boolean append)
           throws IOException
```

> Constructs a FileWriter object given a File object. If the second argument is true, then bytes will be written to the end of the file rather than the beginning.